# $route.reload not working angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I wanted to use 'reload' button so that it would be used to reload data in `ng-view` without reloading the entire page for that I used `$route.reload` inside a function in `custom.js` which I desired to trigger using `ng-click` inside a button in `students.html` page.
But It didn't work giving an error of `not a function` in console.
when I remove parameter `$route` from controller and the corresponding function of `$route.reload` from my file `custom.js` my page works fine.

I am beginner in `angularjs`.

Please comment for any query.

here is my code of `index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html  ng-app="myModule">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head> 
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row body">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#!/home">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#!/students">Students</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-md-8 col-xs-12">
                <p>Website Contents</p>
                <ng-view></ng-view>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="custom.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

here is code for `custom.js`

```
var myApp = angular.module("myModule",["ngRoute"])
                   .config(function($routeProvider){
                       $routeProvider
                           .when("/home",{
                                template : "<h3> \
                                            Home \
                                          </h3> \
                                          <p> \
                                            This is a sample text. \
                                          </p>",
                                controller : "homeController",
                              controllerAs : "homeCtrl"
                            })
                           .when("/students",{
                                templateUrl : "files/students.html",
                                controller : "studentController",
                              controllerAs : "studentCtrl"
                            })
                         .otherwise({
                              redirectTo : "/home"
                         });
                   })
                   .controller("homeController",function(){
                        this.message = "Home";
                   })
                   .controller("studentController",function($http,$route){
                        var virtual_stu_ctrl = this;
                        virtual_stu_ctrl.reloadData1() = function(){
                          $route.reload();
                        }
                        virtual_stu_ctrl.message = "Students";
                        virtual_stu_ctrl.students = [ { "id": "1", "name": "Aditi Musunur" }, 
                                                      { "id": "2", "name": "Jitendra Choudhary" },
                                                      { "id": "8", "name": "Kanyana Saunak" }];

                   });
```

Here is the code for `home.html`

```
<h1>
    {{ homeCtrl.message }}
</h1>
<div>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
    tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
    consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
    cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
    proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
```

here is code for `students.html`

```
<h1>
    {{ studentCtrl.message }}
</h1>
<div>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="student in studentCtrl.students">
                {{ student.name }}
        </li>
    </ul>
    <br />
    <button ng-click="studentCtrl.reloadData1()">Reload Data</button>
</div>
```

Comment: virtual_stu_ctrl.reloadData1() = function(){  -   may be it good to remove the "()" before the  "="?, so it will :virtual_stu_ctrl.reloadData1 = function()

Comment: after you clicking "reload" all javascript objects initialize again as if page was just loaded... if you want only to change data - you can modify the virtual_stu_ctrl.students without call "reload", for example virtual_stu_ctrl.students.push({ "id": "1879", "name": "Teodor Herzel" })

Comment: Hey its working ignore my previous comment